# Blank Page for newly uploaded products in magento

Tags: magento, product

After uploading new products to my existing stockpile (in Magento) I noticed that the product pages were coming up blank. I have reindexed the products, refreshed the cache, ensured that the items are marked as enabled, in stock with a quantity of at least 1. My existing products are working fine so this is a complete mystery to me.

I have found issues such as "Magento shows blank/empty page. How do I solve this?" (http://kb.magenting.com/content/22/38/en/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this.html) but none that with the same problem as me here.

Ideally someone who's reading this has suffered as I am here and healed the pain - if you have please post the cure. Similarly if anyone can suggest solutions/reasons I'd be most grateful.

_g

Comment: I have just run into the problem and perhaps this will help someone else out there - in the "design" of the product I had a "Page Layout" of "No Layer Updates" whereas I had ealier made customisations in the product "layout.xml" file to have "2 columns with left bar"_

Answer (score 0):

Without more information these are just guesses:

- Examine your import script against an export script.  Did you include all core fields e.g. website, store, sku, name
- Check your logs, are any exceptions being thrown on the product page?
- Are the products showing up in your catalog? If so you've probably got the core fields imported ok.  If not see the first point.
- If the products are in the catalog but blank screening on the product page, it's most probably some customer code in your skin thats causing the issue.   Try either switching to the default skin and reload.  If it works then your import was probably missing an attribute used by your skin on the product page.
- If the default skin loads.  Go back to your skin and comment out code on your product page until you find the culprit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate that but I have posted the solution to my problem which i cropped upon above. Perhaps these are good cross-checks for those with similar issues though.. thanks again_g